# Replace <hr> line by image

Tags: html, css

I want to have a custom `<hr>` such that, instead of rendering a plain line, it repeats an image to create a line.

This is the code I currently use

```
hr {
    border: 0;
    background: url(hr.png) repeat-x;
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify a `height`:

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qW6z9/)**

```
hr{
    border:0;
    height:20px;
    background:url(http://placehold.it/20);
}
```